# Conditional probablity on processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Assume I have a stochastic process $X(t)$ adapted to its natural filtration and define the value function

$$ F(t,x) = \mathbb E[ g(X(T))\: |\: X(t) = x ] $$

For some $T>0$. Moreover, define the function

$$ G(s,y) = \mathbb E[ h(F(t, X(t))) \: |\: X(s) = y ], $$

for $T \geq t \geq s$. Then, is this true?

$$ G(s,y) = h(F(s,y)). $$

I believe so, but I was not able to show it.

Comment: Try an example: if $X$ is a Brownian motion and the functions are $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x^2$, then $F(t,x)=x$ hence $G(s,y)=E(X(t)^2\mid X(s)=y)=y^2+t-s\ne y^2=h(F(s,y))$.

Comment: Ah thank you very much. Is the identity still false if $h(x)=x$ and any $g$? I couldn't find a similar false example using the Brownian motion.

Comment: If $h$ is the identity, the property holds, and it follows directly from what is often called the tower property.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess you also have to use the fact that $X(T)$ is independent of $X(s)$ if given $X(t)$. Thank you very much for your answers.